# How route restify calls to function written in another file

Tags: node.js, mongoose, restify

I have a file that launch nodejs/restify server, when calls arrive to my server i do this:

```
apiserver.post('/:param',call1);

function call1(req, res, next) {
//treatment
}
```

But i want to place my functions in a script called functions.js, the problem is when i do this

```
var functions = require('./functions')
apiserver.post('/:param', functions.call1(req,res,next));
```

it say that req, res and next is undefiened variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `functions.call1` in your `apiserver.post` call when what you want to do is pass the function itself as a parameter:

```
apiserver.post('/:param', functions.call1);
```